Looking for short story about a girl called June and her summer experience
When I was in 8th grade, we had an English literature class and we read a lot of short stories. The year was around 1998 and the books where scholastic books that the school used.
The story that I am looking for is about a teenage girl called June, she moved from outside the city (I think from the countryside) to the city. She goes to the public swimming pool and tries to grow some plants on the roof of her apartment building. I think she lived only with her mom and the story focuses on her getting used to the city. I think the story is set during the summer. I kind of remember the story and for some reason it struck a cord with me.
If anyone has an idea of the name of the story I would really appreciate it.

I believe you might be remembering two distinct short stories, both of which I also read in school (much more recently), and which appear to be commonly taught in middle/high schools:
"Tuesday of the Other June" by Norma Fox Mazer, in which a girl named June is bullied by another girl named June (PDF),
and "Antaeus" by Borden Deal, in which a teenage boy moves from the country to the city and, with his new friends, attempts to grow a rooftop garden.
(Wikipedia Page)
(PDF)

Thank you very much, I think you are right. I read them 3 decades ago and they held a spot in my heart.
